# Excel VBA, Sort according to a specific limit

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote an Excel VBA code but for some reason it's not working completly fine.
I have a specific length of 21 (cell E2) and a list of sotred numbers below (column E in the picture)
The code runs on each cell in column E and adds it's value to a specific sum. if the sum up to this cell is lower or equel to 21 (cell E2) then the cell on the right gets the number "1". If it's higher then 21 then we restart the sum and do it again until we reach the limit (21) and all the cells on the right get the number "2" and so on until the end of the list.
As you can see from the picture its working except for the last cell (colored in yellow) where it's supposed to be 4 and not 3 (because 5+5+5+4+3=22>21)

[image]

I can't find where I have a problem. This is my code:

```
   Length = Range("E2").Value
   Range("E3").Select
   i = 1
   sumOfLen = 0

    Do Until Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value = Empty
        Do Until sumOfLen > Length Or Selection.Value = Empty
            Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = i
            sumOfLen = sumOfLen + Selection.Value
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        sumOfLen = 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're resetting the sum to 0 rather than the current Range's value (e.g. 5).

May I suggest the following code?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub doIt()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim curSum As Long
    Dim maxSum As Long
    Dim curRange As Range

    maxSum = Range("E2").Value
    Set curRange = Range("E3")
    i = 1

    Do While (curRange.Value <> "")
        curSum = curSum + curRange.Value
        If (curSum > maxSum) Then
            i = i + 1
            curSum = curRange.Value
        End If

        curRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = i
        Set curRange = curRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

If you'd like to keep your code, you need to change this:

`sumOfLen = 0`

to this

`sumOfLen = Selection.Value`